# Align inside div to bottom center without creating wrapper div or using margin/left in px

Tags: html, css

Please see JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/76yKL/

Is there a way to align "ruler-mark-short" and "ruler-mark-high" divs to the bottom *and* center of their parents("ruler-mark-container") ?

Since width of "ruler-mark-short" and "ruler-mark-high" can be changed dynamically by JavaScript, I can't use 'margin' or 'left' in pixels.
So, I have to use something like "margin: 0 auto" or "text-align: center", but non of this works.

I'm struggling with aligning ruler-marks to both bottom and center without using additional wrapper container.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Code From JSfiddle above:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="ruler">
        <div class="ruler-mark-container">
            <div class="ruler-mark-high"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ruler-mark-container">
            <div class="ruler-mark-short"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ruler-mark-container">
            <div class="ruler-mark-short"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ruler-mark-container">
            <div class="ruler-mark-short"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ruler-mark-container">
            <div class="ruler-mark-short"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ruler-mark-container">
            <div class="ruler-mark-high"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    position: absolute;
    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
}

.ruler {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.ruler-mark-container {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    float: left;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.ruler-mark-high {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: grey;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 3px;
    height: 50px;
}

.ruler-mark-short {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: grey;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 3px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/76yKL/1/

Comment: Not exactly, if you change width of "ruler-mark-high" or "ruler-mark-short" it won't be centered anymore.
See this: http://jsfiddle.net/76yKL/3/

But thanks. Nice try :)

Comment: Ok, so the width can be changed after page load, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The width can be changed after page load by JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-align:center` does not work with absolutely positioned elements. So remove absolute position, and format them using `display:inline-block`.

Without absolute positioning, they won’t be at the bottom any more of course. To fix that, stop floating the container elements, and display them as `table-cell` instead, and add `vertical-align:bottom` to both containers and markers.

http://jsfiddle.net/76yKL/7/

Comment: Wow, that's very very good, thank you. 
Seems like that is correct answer, will it work in IE8+ and Safari too?

Comment: It should, at least in theory: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Browser_compatibility, http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table Wether or not additional fixes might be required, is for you to test :-)

Comment: It does work in IE9, IE10, I'll test in everything else.
Thank you very much, you helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the following css:

```
.ruler-mark-short, .ruler-mark-high{
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -1.5px;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76yKL/4/)**

**UPDATED**: (IE9+)

```
.ruler-mark-short, .ruler-mark-high{
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    /* Add other vendor prefixes here */
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76yKL/6/)**

Comment: I've stated in the question, that I can't use margin or left(or margin-left), because I can't guarantee, that div is 3px in width.
But thanks, any more ideas without strict "px" for margin of left?

Comment: @JoeSmith check my updated post.. doesn't work in IE8 though.

Comment: Ah, I do need IE8+, Chrome and Safari, but that was awesome try.
Upvote for sure. Thank you, any more ideas to handle IE8 too though? :)

Comment: @JoeSmith do you know height of those bars?

Comment: I know what you're trying, you want to use top in pixels? :)

No, I don't know the height too, sorry.
So, no dimensions are known in pixels, but I do need to align it to bottom center without knowing height or width.

Comment: I do like it, but I've stated that I don't want to use additional container, sorry :)
And by the way, if you use additional wrapper container I think it will be possible to align it to the bottom and then just align the inner "ruler-mark-short" to center.